# attr in combo with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a combo with hidden attribute.

```
<select name="myCombo" class="combo" id="myCombo">

    <option value="01" dataMyData="AAAA">The text</option>
 </select>
```

To get "dataMyData" I use:

```
$('option:selected', myCombo).attr('dataMyData');
```

Which works fine in Chrome but fails in IE

'myCombo' is not defined.

How can I access to this data in order to work in IE?

Comment: Have you defined variable as `myCombo`? As an alternative you can use `$('#myCombo option:selected').attr('dataMyData');`

Comment: it works fine! thanks

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
<option value="01" dataMyData="AAAA">The text</option>
```

with this

```
<option value="01" data-my-data="AAAA">The text</option>
```